# How to zip all sub folders inside folder with a specific name

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to find all folders with the name "Logfile" inside slightly different folder structures. For example how would I find the Logfile folder inside C:\ECU\ECU1\Logfile, C:\ECU\ECU2\Logfile, C:\ECU\ECU3\Logfile and C:\ECU\ECU4\Logfile? I then want to zip the .txt contents of this folder in each case. I currently have a batch file running which allows me to zip the contents of a folder which has the same folder structure each time but need to combine the above all together. Any help would be great...

Thanks.

```
@echo off
 pushd "C:\ECU\ECU2" || goto :eof

REM zip all files in the backup directory
 FOR %%A IN (*.TXT*, *.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
 FOR %%A IN (*.TXT,*.cpi) DO DEL "C:\ECU\ECU2.cpi*" "%%A"
 popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a test first to see if it prints the correct folders:

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\ecu" %%a in (target*) do (
if /i "%%~nxa"=="target" (
echo "%%a"
)
)
pause
```

and if it's ok then this should work - test it with dummy files, but your `DEL` command is odd in the first term.  I replaced it with what might work.

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\ecu" %%a in (target*) do (
if /i "%%~nxa"=="target" (
pushd "%%a"
REM zip all files in the backup directory
 FOR %%A IN (*.TXT* *.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
 FOR %%A IN (*.TXT *.cpi) DO DEL "%%A"
 popd 
)
)
```